# Term rewriting inside dependantly typed expression fails for unknown reason

Tags: coq

Here is a simplified snippet of a larger proof which captures the behavior in question.

```
Section foo.
  Parameter t : Type.
  Parameter x : t.
  Parameter y : t.
  Parameter prop : x = y <-> True.
  Parameter prop2 : x = y.
  Lemma lemma : forall e : t, x = y.
    rewrite prop2.
    intro e; trivial.
    Qed.
End foo.
```

When you replace `rewrite prop2` by `rewrite prop` coq fails with cryptic errors. However in my oppinion coq ought to yield `forall e : t, True` after the rewriting step. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Note that "intros; rewrite prop" works, because "iff" is a registered setoid equality. I'm not sure what the error message means. However, Coq appears to be checking whether (iff ==> impl) (arrow) is an instance of proper.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [reference manual](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#@tactic102):

```
rewrite term
This tactic applies to any goal. The type of term must have the form
forall (x1:A1) … (xn:An)eq term1 term2.
where eq is the Leibniz equality or a registered setoid equality.
```

But `prop` is not in a form with Leibniz equality:

```
Coq < Unset Printing Notations.
Coq < Print prop.
prop : iff (eq x y) True
```

So coq requires Setoid to check if `iff` is setiod equality.